# When the yellow lights (on a sign?) are flashing, the driver must reduce speed to a maximum of 30 km/h and yield or stop for pedestrians

Tags: traffic, interpretation, alberta

Is the following statement saying that when the yellow lights on the sign (see below) start flashing, caution is required? I asked the question because they don't look "electronic" to me. Maybe it's referring to some other yellow lights?

"[Yellow lights on a sign with a symbol indicate that caution is required because of school zones or areas, playground zones or areas, school crossings, and pedestrian crossings. When the yellow lights are flashing, the driver must reduce speed to a maximum of 30 km/h and yield or stop for pedestrians.](https://www.alberta.ca/pedestrian-signals-and-signs.aspx#:%7E:text=When%20the%20yellow%20lights%20are,yield%20or%20stop%20for%20pedestrians.)"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the two yellow symbols either side of the walking man image, which are representations of "electronic" lights.

Follow your link to see the text immediately below the sign:

> Pedestrian crossing sign with yellow lights

See this similar example (from Nova Scotia):

[image]

[Source](https://www.saltwire.com/nova-scotia/opinion/your-letters-preventing-crosswalk-casualties-564036/)

Comment: Think you so very much for your detailed answer!